# Webmatrix/Razor and Stored procedure with OUT parameter

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, razor, webmatrix

I am trying WebMatrix for the first time and based on various forums, I put together the code to execute a stored procedure (in SQL Server 2008) but I need to retrieve output value from the stored procedure back in an OUTPUT parameter.

I use the following code:

```
@(
   var strInputParam = "Test";
   var strOutputParam = "";
   var db = Database.Open("mydatabase");
   var selectQueryString = "EXECUTE dbo.SP_Test @0, @1";
   //var selectQueryString = "EXECUTE dbo.SP_Test @0, @1 OUTPUT";
   db.Execute(selectQueryString, strInputParam, strOutputParam);
}
```

When I run this, the procedure runs but "strOutputParam" is still empty after the execution. I have also tried the version in the commented code as an alternative but that brings back empty value as well.

Is there anything specific I need to do to retrieve the OUTPUT param value?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Database helper doesn't support output parameters. It was never designed to work with stored procedures. You can use plain ADO.NET instead.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I guess I have to go back to regular programming. For once I thought I could put things together and won't have to reinvent the wheel :-(

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but just in case some one else wants the answer,

If your query returns only one value:

```
var strOutputParam = db.QueryValue(selectQueryString, strInputParam, strOutputParam);
```

If your query returns an entire row:

```
var strOutputParam = db.QueryValue(selectQueryString, strInputParam, strOutputParam);
var col1 = strOutputParam.col1;
var col2 = strOutputParam.col2;
```

If your query returns multiple rows:

```
foreach (var strOutputParam in db.QueryValue(selectQueryString, strInputParam, strOutputParam){

}
```